# Logical reads and LOB logical reads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, database-internals

I have a query app scanning a whole table with a text field.

The query is doing this many reads:

> Scan count 1, **logical reads 170586**, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads
> 174716, **lob logical reads 7902578**, lob physical reads 8743, lob
> read-ahead reads 0.

[Query plan with lob logical reads](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkOSZVZA9)

If I remove the text field from the select, reads become the following:

> Scan count 1, **logical reads 170588**, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads
> 0, **lob logical reads 0**, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

[Query plan without lob logical reads](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJgQzN-A5)

The thing that I don't get is how lob reads works:

if I sum up the logical reads with lob logical reads I get a total of **8.073.164 logical reads**, which, if I'm correct, is **about 64GB**.

But the entire database is only 7GB!

I'm probably missing something about adding up logical reads and lob logical reads.

What does the number of lob logical reads actually represent?

Comment: I believe the execution plan for both situations are gonna be needed to understand the difference. It could be that your 1st query is reading the clustered index and the 2nd another index which does not contain that text field. About that large amount of logical reads, it could be a badly written query making use of [RBAR](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/) and causing the table to be read way too many times to complete.

Comment: Hi Ronaldo! No differences at all: just a plain and simple select statement on a single table with no join and no where clause. The only difference is the list of columns in the select.

The execution plan for both queries is just a clustered inxed scan.

I'll provide both plans inside the question anyway

Comment: Even for a simple `SELECT` with just a clustered index scan is still worth sharing the actual execution plan for which contains a lot of runtime information encoded in it besides just the operators. But I agree with Tibor that your query is probably resulting in the same data pages to be read multiple times, compounding the amount of data being read off disk.

Comment: @J.D. Query plans added!

Comment: `ActualLobLogicalReads` is `0` in both of those plans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally get it now. `SET STATISTICS IO ON` shows 8.073.164 lob logical reads, which is **exactly** the total number of records * 2.

That's because LOB data is stored in a B-Tree structure like normal pages! So, for every row, you perform 2 additional logical reads: one for the root page, and the other for the data itself.

That is in my specific case, because the largest text inside the table is only 24 bytes.

[Source](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2225060)

Answer (score 5):

Here's my theory,

These are logical reads, not physical reads. Imagine two rows, where the LOB data for these rows is on the same page (yes, pages can be shared across rows for LOB data).

Perhaps each read only reads, say, 100 bytes. Each read is still a logical read.

Furthermore, you say that these are text data type, for which the default is to *not* have the LOB data in-row. If the type instead were varbinary(max), then the default *is* to have LOB data in-row (as long as it fits on the page). This can make a big difference, what is best depends on whether you frequently need the LOB data or not. You can reconfigure this (for both types) using sp_tableoption.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I understand your answer: you're telling that 1 lob logical reads is equal to 1 byte?

Comment: No that it now what I'm saying. Two rows can point to the same LOB page. Say that your SELECT read those two rows (only for sake of example), you have now two logical reads to that same page. Say that each row only has 100 bytes LOB data, you now did two logical read that read 200 bytes. Your calculation assumes that each logical read is 8 KB, which my example show that it doesn't have to me.

Comment: Ok, so, while every logical read is 8KB, a lob logical reads can be anything, it depends on  the content of the column. 

Do you have any official documentation that says that? Cause I don't think that's the case

Comment: I think we might be talking about different things here, or misunderstand each other. You ask why can you have LOB logical reads that sums up to more than the database size. The answer is that the query can read the same LOB page over and over again (first read might be physical, subsequent reads might be only logical since the page is now possibly in cache). For each row you get a logical read to fetch the data, potentially several rows reads the same page (over and over again).

Comment: @MattiaNocerino Two different rows of data in your table might be stored in the same 8 KB page of data. If your query returns both those rows, then the same 8 KB page of data is read from twice. So yes, it's 2 LOB logical reads, but from the same 8 KB page of data. Think of it like a book, and each page in the book is the equivalent of a data page in the database. Two  different sentences may be on the same page. You open the book, turn to page 42 and read the first sentence. You jump to another page to read some other sentence. You jump back to the page 42 to read the second sentence.

Comment: @J.D. I understand, but you shouldn't have more lob logical reads than the number of total records.

The entire table has 4.037.126 rows and the lob logical reads are 8.074.252 which is exactly the double! So for every row it's doing 2 lob logical reads... how can this be?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino It sounds like you don't understand then. The question you just asked me is "*how can a book have 100 pages but someone reads from the pages 200 times?*" - Well easy, if someone only reads the first few sentences of a particular page then jumps to another page and reads some more, then jumps back to the **same** first page they started on and reads a few other sentences from a different part of that page. Also keep in mind, a page is only 8 KB big. A single row in a database with a very large text field will take up multiple pages. E.g. an 80 KB text field will use 10 pages.

Comment: @J.D. I'm probably not understanding as you say, but the following query

`SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(PATH)) FROM DBO.FILEMANAGEMENT`

Returns 24. So multiple records should fit in a page.

The fact that the query is performing *exactly* double the number of records of lob logical reads sounds like it's a bug

Comment: @MattiaNocerino I'll try this one last time. You take a book out from the library. It has 2 pages total in it. Open the book, read the first sentence from the first page. Then go to the second page, read the first sentence in the second page. Then go back to the first page, read the last sentence on the page. Finally go back to the second page, and read the last sentence. How many **times** did you read from a page in the book? The answer is 4, even though there's only 2 pages total in the book.

Comment: @J.D. I completely get what you're saying, now I'll try for the last time.  

You have a table with 100 rows. Every row has a text column which is stored in another page. To read that data, you have to perform a LOB logical read. You're damn sure that every LOB data in the table is less than 25 bytes, so there's no row that spans multiple pages. Every row then should equal to 1 lob logical reads.

How many lob logical reads do you perform when you scan the entire table?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino Depends how many times the table is scanned based on the execution plan of the query you're running. In your linked example the `ActualLobLogicalReads` is 0 (as pointed out by Charlieface). So in your case it looks like 0.